# What does the sound "app" mean in Chinese?

Tags: meaning

I noticed that Chinese sometimes prefer to say "ay pee pee" rather than just "app" when referring to a computer application. I infer there is a chance that "app" already had a meaning in a Chinese language other than application. Can anyone tell me what meaning it may have in Mandarin or Cantonese? Thanks.

Comment: "App" is not a valid syllable in Mandarin, so I imagine the pronunciation A-P-P was easier to pronounce for some people.

Comment: This is part of a larger trend, too, people say L-E-D for LED as well, for instance. My guess is that these are more easily accepted as new words (even though they are original abbreviations) in English because they don't violate morphological rules as much as they do in Chinese. Also, I suspect that single-syllable foreign words pronounced in the middle of a Chinese sentence will be much harder to understand than a three-syllable abbreviation, which is obviously not a Chinese word.

Comment: @OlleLinge, LED is pronounced as an initialism in English as well, in fact (in my experience at least) more commonly than as an acronym.

Comment: Perhaps a bad example then (but would you really say L-E-D display, for instance?), but I still think the general tendency is there (of not making words of acronyms in Chinese, I mean).

Comment: My own experience is, it depends on how natural/convenient it is pronounced when we embed it into a Chinese sentence. Here're some examples that most Chinese people would pronounce as acronyms: PIN, SARS, Ajax, SOHO, COM, FLAC, grep, GRID.

Comment: As a Chinese, I assure you that A-P-P means nothing else. People just used to spell it in this way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @OlleLinge Yes, the usual way to say it in English is "L-E-D display" (at least in American English AFAIK).

Comment: The poster is not asking how 'app' is pronounced, but whether it has other meanings aside from a computer/mobile application.

Comment: I believe APP is just used for mobile applications. Otherwise people would(should?) usually use 软件.

Comment: Because lots of Chinese are unfamiliar to the rules of English Pronunciation but can read each letter, you can also hear Chinese say "S-I-M", "U-G-G" etc., I personally also just read the letters of those words before I came to Au.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't have any meaning in Mandarin itself, given that "words" in Mandarin end with either a vowel, "n", or "ng" (as per the pinyin romanization). It could be another word from English but I doubt it (given that I can't think of any other words with similar spelling/pronunciation in common usage). Moreover, in my experience, most people who speak Mandarin just use "app".

In my experience Cantonese speaking people seem more inclined to use "app" as well, even though there *are* a couple characters with slightly similar pronuncation (but as obvious, significantly different tones) in Cantonese, such as 鸭 (*aap* with the jyutping romanization system). That said, given the tonal nature of the words in Cantonese and the fact that there is still a different pronunciation, I don't think there's any risk of confusing "app" with any of those words.

(However, it's worth noting that my experiences have mainly been around Cantonese/Mandarin speakers who probably are inclined to [code-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching) with English words and phrases than average.)

To conclude, I'd say that while there might indeed be Chinese speakers who pronounce "app" as "A-P-P", I wouldn't attribute this to any words in Chinese with similar pronunciation and different meaning.

Comment: “So I downloaded this duck onto my phone yesterday …”

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be obvious that app(/æp/) stands for application(/æplɪˈkeɪʃn/), most Chinese just say "A-P-P" because they simply have no idea what does it represent and won't notice the correlation between "app" and "application" for the first time they see it(which might be the same situation even if they're getting more familiar with the word add).

Answer (score 0):

Still a lot of people in China can not understand English very well, just like say 'app'. Pronounce them seperately is easier for most Chinese people.